# Empty MappedType when creating type from imported interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I defined some interfaces in a file named `interfaces.ts` and attempted to import them into a different file, `consumeInterfaces.ts`, to create a mapped type. However, the resulting mapped type resolved to an empty object.

```js
// interfaces.ts

export interface Foo {}
export interface Bar {}
export interface Baz {}
...
```

Now in `consumeInterfaces.ts`, I want to import all interfaces defined in `interfaces.ts` and create a mapped type like so:

```js
// consumeInterfaces.ts
import * as MyInterfaces from 'interfaces.ts'

type NamespaceInterfaces = typeof MyInterfaces;
type MappedType = {
  [K in keyof NamespaceInterfaces ]: Map<string, NamespaceInterfaces[K]>
};
```

However, when I inspected the resulting MappedType, it was an empty object {} instead of the expected type with mapped properties.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `typeof MyInterfaces` is `{}`. There's no runtime values in `MyInterfaces`. It's just a namespace. Also, what you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: I see, because I am using `keyof` it's reading the value of `NamespaceInterfaces` at runtime which is empty since types do not exist during runtime. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, and there's no way to achieve what you are looking for, besides doing it manually

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud:

```js
export interface MyInterfaces {
  Foo: {}
  Bar: {}
  Baz: {}
}
export type Foo = MyInterfaces['Foo'];
export type Bar = MyInterfaces['Bar'];
export type Baz = MyInterfaces['Baz'];
```

```js
import { MyInterfaces } from './interfaces.ts'

type MappedType = {
  [K in keyof MyInterfaces ]: Map<string, MyInterfaces[K]>
};
```

That said, I'm not sure what your goal is. It seems to me you could just write:

```js
export interface MyInterfaces {
  Foo: Map<string, {}>
  Bar: Map<string, {}>
  Baz: Map<string, {}>
}
export type Foo = MyInterfaces['Foo'];
export type Bar = MyInterfaces['Bar'];
export type Baz = MyInterfaces['Baz'];
```

Unless you plan on using something other than `{}` for each Map, in which case, you could probably just do:

```js
export interface MyFoo { ... };
export interface MyBar { ... };
export interface MyBaz { ... };
export interface MyInterfaces {
  Foo: Map<string, MyFoo>
  Bar: Map<string, MyBar>
  Baz: Map<string, MyBaz>
}
```

And omit the mapped types altogether.